# C++ segmentation fault in linux

Tags: c++, linux, debugging

This is the segmentation fault error that I am having. I don't even know any commands to make it go away or know what the problem is .

But when I am compiling with the -g flag , it compiles fine but I want to do it without using any flag which it isn't doing.

This is the error i am getting

```
cc1plus: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/cc0bBW1Q.out file, please attach this to your bugreport.
cc1plus: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/ccecNlWl.out file, please attach this to your bugreport.
```

Comment: You're upsetting the compiler.  It would help if you showed what you are trying to compile.

Comment: Reduce the code to the minimal amount which still produces the error and post it here! Also, to be able to tell what's going wrong exactly, you'd need to mention the exact version of the compiler (use `g++ -v` to find out). Most likely, the code you are trying to compile is questionable in some form, causing the compiler to crash. It is, however, a bug even if the code passed to isn't perfect!

Comment: See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.

Comment: @JohnAuld "http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla%3E" isn't going to go anywhere. Try [`http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla`](http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla)

Comment: @WhozCraig, that was a copy/paste from OP. Editing it would have reduced the rhetorical value. That's my story, and I'm sticking to it.

Comment: @JohnAuld good god I feel like a putz now, raining on that parade of satire and all. I'm sorry, man. I didn't even consider it. I'll try and be more attentive =P